# How to Check length of file before uploading to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, file-upload, quota

[image]
We are working on a Quota Increase scenario. Can anybody tell me  how the any document/media file is uploaded in SharePoint ? Is there any way, we can programmatically check the size of the every document before actually uploading to the SharePoint site ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the File Size limit at Document library level OOTB. What you need, you have to write your own code may be some event receiver.

Check this code from [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4ae013fd-57ab-4219-9caf-27495d564602/sharepoint-2010-limit-file-uploading-size-for-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

```
{
     long validFileSize;
     long currentFileSize;
     if (properties.ListItem == null)
     {
             using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
             {
                    if (!web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
                   {
                          if (properties.ListTitle.ToLower() == "images")
                         {
                                 if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"] != null)
                                 {
                                        validFileSize = long.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"].ToString());
                                 }
                                 else
                                {
                                       validFileSize = 1000000;//1MB
                                }
                               currentFileSize = long.Parse(properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"].ToString());
                               if (currentFileSize > validFileSize)
                              {
                                      return false;
                              }
                        }
                 }
          }
    }
    else if (properties.ListItem.ParentList.Title.ToLower() == "images")
    {
          if (!properties.ListItem.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin) 
         {
                 if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"] != null)
                 {
                        validFileSize = long.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"].ToString());
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        validFileSize = 1000000;//1MB
                 }
                 currentFileSize = properties.ListItem.File.TotalLength;
                 if (currentFileSize > validFileSize)
                {
                      return false;
                }
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ref: [How to limit the file upload size for a specific document library in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113453/how-to-limit-the-file-upload-size-for-a-specific-document-library-in-sharepoint)

Comment: We are looking for SharePoint auto- quota  increase  which is available in office 365 . How can we implement that same feature in on Premise ?